# JVM Launcher cannot find main class

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, classpath

I am using NetBeans to build my executable JAR and haven't messed around with any Ant or project settings (using defaults).

When I go to `Run >> Clean and Build Project`, I see NetBeans building my JAR and putting it into my project's `dist/` directory without a hitch.

When I double-click that JAR to run it, I get the following error message:

> Could not find the main class: com.me.myorg.MainApp. Program will exit.

If I open up the JAR in WinRAR and extract the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, I see the following attribute defined:

> Main-Class: com.me.myorg.MainApp

Obviously, `com.me.myorg.MainApp` is the "head" of my GUI (Swing) app.

Any ideas as to what is going on? How to troubleshoot? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it have a proper main method, is the path from the jar root to the MainApp classfile `/com/me/myorg`? (eliminating the obvious first)

Comment: Are you _certain_ the com.me.myorg.MainApp class is in your jar, and in the correct location?

Comment: Yes it has a main method, and this JAR was working fine several weeks ago (I could execute it by double-clicking it) and no source code has changed.

Comment: Thorn - yes - please see my followup to Caner's suggestion below. I think it is indicative of a Windows security issue, but I'm still lost as to what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in command prompt(Windows):

```
ftype jarfile="C:\PATH_TO\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %
```

**EDIT**
Run the command prompt like this: Go to Start and in the Search box type CMD. Right click the Command Prompt icon and choose **Run as Administrator**.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/

Then run the command above.

Comment: I have several versions of Java installed on my system. How do I tell which one is being used when I double-click the executable JAR?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if I did this with the right version of Java, but I used `java -version` on the command prompt to discover I was using Java 6u25, and then executed that command above using the absolute file path to 6u25's `javaw.exe` file, and I got the following error message: **Access is denied. Error occurred while processing: jarfile.**

Comment: In control panel, there is a shortcut to "Java control panel". There go to the tab named "Java"

Comment: Thanks Caner, but when I go to that tab it just shows a table with all the versions of Java I have installed. I *believe* I'm using 1.6u25 which is what I get by running `java -version` on the command-line.

Comment: Thanks Caner - here's the output when ran as admin: `jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %`

Comment: This could also happen if netbeans is compiling with different Java version than your command prompt uses. Check the Java version used to build your jar file and use the same Java version for the `ftype` command

Answer (score 0):

Is there a new line after the main class declaration?

```
Main-Class: com.me.myorg.MainApp
# empty line here
```

The manifest file format requires each line to end with a line separator. If the line with main class is the last line in the file it is ignored.

Comment: Actually there are two empty lines beneath `Main-Class`. Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: Not really. Does running the program from cmd.exe with `java -jar yourfile.jar` give a different message? And does `java -cp yourfile.jar com.me.myorg.MainApp` start it normally?